# How to insert an array as an object into another array in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to create a replies array that has nested child replies.

Ex:

```
const [replies, setReplies] = useState([
{
    id: 1,
    user: "user1",
    comment: "test"
    replies: [] //In here should be another array that contains other reply objects 
},
{
    id: 2,
    user: "user2",
    comment: "test2"
    replies: [{
        id: 1,
        parent_id: 1,
        user: "user2",
        comment: "test2"
        replies: []
    }]
}
])
```

Data is requested through axios from a MySQL database and I have two separate tables for a parent reply and a child reply. **The child replies** must be included **inside replies object** - **inside the parent reply array** like above.

How can I achieve this? (React v17.0.2)

--- updated

Here's what the actual JSON response looks like;

```
{
"replies": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 31,
            "user_name": "admin",
            "replied_to": null,
            "post_id": 1,
            "replied_time": "2021-12-28 19:00:01",
            "description": "test",
            "likes": 0,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "replies": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user_id": 53,
            "user_name": "godfrey",
            "replied_to": null,
            "post_id": 1,
            "replied_time": "2021-12-28 19:20:35",
            "description": "test2",
            "likes": 0,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "replies": null
        }
    ],
    "child_replies": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "user_id": 57,
            "post_id": 1,
            "replied_time": "2021-12-28 19:30:02",
            "description": "test3",
            "likes": 0,
            "dislikes": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "user_id": 59,
            "post_id": 1,
            "replied_time": "2021-12-28 19:42:02",
            "description": "test4",
            "likes": 0,
            "dislikes": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the objects inside **child_replies** to be inserted into **replies object** inside the **parent replies array**

Comment: please add the logic you've tried

Comment: @MohitKushwaha 

I call this method inside useEffects where I also receive the SQL response from axios.

`const populateReplies = () => {
    unsortedReplies.map((reply) => {
      setSortedReplies(...sortedReplies, reply);
    });

    sortedReplies.map((reply) => {
      unsortedChildReplies.forEach((childReply) => {
        if (reply.id === childReply.parent_id) {
          setSortedReplies({ ...sortedReplies.replies, replies: childReply });
        }
      });
    });
  };`

Doesn't work as I intended though.

Comment: As you mentioned you want to populate the  parent replies with their respective child replies I've implemented the logic, please see this https://codepen.io/Mohit_codes/pen/gOGvMbd?editors=0012

Comment: @MohitKushwaha

Oh it works superbly! Thank you for your time! One more thing if you don't mind please, is it possible for the result obtained from the callback to be set to a useState array?

Comment: please check this https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-29dec-inign?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Awesome! Thank you once again for your help! If you state the code as an answer I can accept it.
@MohitKushwaha

Comment: ok i am posting it as answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [replies, setReplies] = useState({
    replies: [
      {
        id: 1,
        user_id: 31,
        user_name: "admin",
        replied_to: null,
        post_id: 1,
        replied_time: "2021-12-28 19:00:01",
        description: "test",
        likes: 0,
        dislikes: 0,
        replies: null
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        user_id: 53,
        user_name: "godfrey",
        replied_to: null,
        post_id: 1,
        replied_time: "2021-12-28 19:20:35",
        description: "test2",
        likes: 0,
        dislikes: 0,
        replies: null
      }
    ],
    child_replies: [
      {
        id: 1,
        parent_id: 1,
        user_id: 57,
        post_id: 1,
        replied_time: "2021-12-28 19:30:02",
        description: "test3",
        likes: 0,
        dislikes: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        parent_id: 1,
        user_id: 59,
        post_id: 1,
        replied_time: "2021-12-28 19:42:02",
        description: "test4",
        likes: 0,
        dislikes: 0
      }
    ]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let parent = replies["replies"];
    let childReplies = replies["child_replies"];

    function callback(obj) {
      const childs = childReplies.filter(
        (childObj) => childObj["parent_id"] === obj["id"]
      );
      let childArray = obj.replies === null ? [] : obj.replies;
      childArray = [...childArray, ...childs];
      return { ...obj, replies: childArray };
    }

    const result = parent.map(callback);

    setReplies(result);
  }, []);

  console.log(replies);

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Saved me some time! Thanks! Also if you have the time could you check this as well, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526848/network-requests-are-always-pending-nodejs-axios-reactjs)