# Network requests are always pending - nodejs/axios/reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm working on my first reactjs/nodejs project and I've encountered quite an error that has bugged me for several days now. I think it's a cors issue cause, but not really sure, because every time I send a request to/from the server, it doesn't complete; shows status pending. I use a middleware to authenticate a JWT token and without cors it doesn't let me load any page; else I could've tried what happens if I remove cors.

Below are some images and snippets of the issue at hand.

[Whenever the page loads, some of the select SQL queries won't complete here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rREEF.png)

[Whenever I send a request to update something, it won't complete either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v5zO.png)

Below are some of the requests that hit pending.

```
app.post("/getposttags", (req, res) => {
  const post_id = req.body.post_id;

  let sql =
    "SELECT * FROM tag INNER JOIN post_tag ON post_tag.tag_id = tag.id AND post_tag.post_id = ? GROUP BY tag.name";
  db.query(sql, post_id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({ err: err });
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```
app.post("/userpref", (req, res) => {
  const post_id = req.body.post_id;
  const user_id = req.body.user_id;

  db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM post_pref WHERE user_id = ? AND post_id = ?",
    [user_id, post_id],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ err: err });
      }
      if (result.length > 0) {
        res.send(result[0]);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

```
app.post("/updateleadsprefs", (req, res) => {
  const { id, post_id, user_id, pref, leads } = req.body;

  console.log(req.body);

  if (id > 0) {
    db.query(
      "UPDATE post_pref SET preference = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND post_id = ?",
      [pref, user_id, post_id]
    );
  } else {
    db.query(
      "INSERT INTO post_pref(post_id, user_id, preference) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
      [post_id, user_id, pref]
    );
  }

  db.query("SELECT leads FROM post WHERE id = ?", post_id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({ err: err });
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {
      const newLeads = parseInt(result[0].leads) + leads;
      db.query(
        "UPDATE post SET leads = ? WHERE id = ?",
        [newLeads, post_id],
        (err, updateRes) => {
          if (err) {
            res.send({ err: err });
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
  res.end();
});
```

Although, when I send a request through an onClick method and it hits pending status, restarting the node server a couple times actually sends the request.

These issues however didn't apply for my login queries/requests since it works fine. It happens when I have logged-in and is redirected to the home page where other queries and requests are being sent.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my issue and helping if possible.

Comment: Maybe the db.query are asynchronous functions and needs a .then or async await?

Comment: I did try async await but sadly no change. When I use a .then with db.query, it throws an error - `db.query(...).then is not a function`
@keysl

Comment: Have you tried without the middleware?

Comment: and also try logging the req.body to the nodejs console in requests.

Comment: Thank you for looking into the issue, really appreciate it! Btw, yeah, I tried without the middleware, sadly no luck. Logging the body actually logs only 3 items out of like 9. But once I refresh the server like 2-3 times, the rest of the data keeps logging in 2 or 3 items per refresh. Making a change in the frontend (code-wise in the HTML part inside react component) also seems to work, it's really has turned into an itching bug rn
@MohitKushwaha

Comment: Try commenting off the db query part from every request and simply returning a string in response (without any asynchronous code), and then continue to send requests. If the current issue resolves, then the problem lies with the database query, otherwise, it is something else.

Comment: I put the queries of `getposttags` & `userpref` inside one separate router instead of two and it began to work! Don't really know why but I think it could've been an issue with the db queries, thank you once more!